# Use position in CSS and calculate height

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've set img width 100%, so I don't know height of the img. I'm trying to set a div at the end of img using position absolute and top. Can we use **calc()** ? Or another method.

Note: I've set img position fixed.

```
<div class="container">
<img class="image" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png">
</div>

<div class="to-image-bottom">I'm div at the bottom of image</div>
```

Comment: Short answer: yes, you can do this using css, but only if you know the width/height ratio of the image.

Comment: How do I know the ratio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bottom` instead of `top` for positioning elements. Also use wrapper for bottom div for display it outside of image. For example:

```css
/* Container for image and bottom div */
.container{
  position: relative;
  /* For display content outside of image */
  overflow: visible;
}

/* Image Styles */
.container .image{
  width: 100%;
}

/* Wrapper for bottom div for align to bottom */
.container .to-image-bottom-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

/* Bottom Div */
.container .to-image-bottom-wrapper .to-image-bottom{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* position relative to wrapper */
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png">
    <div class="to-image-bottom-wrapper">
      <div class="to-image-bottom">I'm div at the bottom of image</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Edited for displaying div outside of image

Comment: In my case div with classname "to-image-bottom" is at the outside of the container.

Comment: I don't know why you want to use positioning in this case, 'cause you can just place <div> after <img> tag and div will be displaying after img. You can wrap tags in container div and set for img and inner div 'display: block' and 'width: 100%'